Right node raising of an indirect question and a free relative is possible?
It is well known that indirect questions and free relatives are identical in form.
a. I don’t know [who you chose].    (indirect question)
b. I will marry [who you chose].       (free relative)
c. I don’t know [who you chose] but I will marry [who you chose].
My question is: Is it possible to apply right node raising to these [who you chose] like this?
d.  I don’t know but I will marry [who you chose].    (Right Node Raising)
If possible, can you give another example?

It doesn't sound right to me; I'd prefer "I don’t know who you chose but I will marry them". Maybe someone can provide a more formal explanation.

Very interesting question. The answer is 'NO'. Coordinating them will force an interrogative reading of both. Note that free relatives and indirect questions are only sometimes isomorphic, and when they are, this is arguably only in terms of their superficial surface form, not their actual structure!

Although you said, "Coorinating them will force an interrogative reading of both," it seems to me that it is impossible to interprete "who you chose" after "marry" as a question.

@Kazuhiro7299 No, quite right. It forces it the other way there.
